# Is there a way to run install.packages("devtools") and specify a mirror?

Tags: r, devtools

I'm trying to automate the creation of an environment in Windows and need to install devtools for R.  I can install it manually from R by running install.packages("devtools").  However, when I do this I am prompted to select a mirror.

Is there a way to specify a mirror in a non-interactive way so that this process can be run as part of a larger process?

Comment: You mean to specify the repo: `install.packages("devtools", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")`

Comment: @TarJae:  I don't know currently, but in the past the `cran.us` mirror was fairly unreliable.  I'd recommend `cloud.r-project.org` (or `cran.rstudio.com`, which has been a synonym, but may change since the company changed its name).